# can i submit an app without sizing the screens to work on all iDevices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I've searched far and wide for the answer to this. i haven't been able to find an answer anywhere, so i turned to stack overflow in hopes you would be able to give me an answer. I'm about to submit my first app to the app store. do i have to make the app function on all iDevices (iPad, iPhone 4, iPhone 5, iPod touch, etc.)? or can i just submit my app for one single device and screen size and leave it at that? will they reject it?

i went through this pdf:

```
http://stadium.weblogsinc.com/engadget/files/app-store-guidelines.pdf
```

but i never found an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build the app, in Xcode you select the device families that the app supports. The choice is currently iPhone, iPad, or both. If you choose iPhone, you'll have to support both the 3.5" and 4" screen sizes. If you used Auto Layout, this should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

You specify what kind of device family your app will run. You can not limit your app only to (for example) iPhone 4. As far as I know right now if you specify your app running on iPhones it has to support 3.5 and 4 inches screens. So getting exactly to your question: **no, you can not leave your app running fine only on one device and screen size.**  Except the approval process it would probably cost you very low rating on the App Store.

Comment: Apple will reject an app that does not support the 4 inch form factor if it targets iPhone. While the older 3.5 is not used as much these days, you still want to test it on that form factor.

Comment: Your not wrong, just clarifying if he does not have 4" support, that is an automatic rejection.

Apples official guidelines are here: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/

Comment: yes, you are right, it was early this year this year when that requirement was established as far as I remember

Comment: I think it was last year when they did that. I could be wrong, but the point is now it must support the 4" factor.